# populate combobox with items on single line of text file

Tags: vb.net, combobox, character, readline

I have a line of text A;B;C;D; in a text file. what I'm wanting to achive is to populate a combobox so that it reads as follows
A
B
C
D

Using the ; char as a way to define a new combobox entry.

its supose to work in combination with the following code...

```
        For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\TEST.txt")
        If line.StartsWith("+dep+") Then
            ComboBox1.Text = line.Substring(5)
        End If
```

which selects a tag from a file with alsorts of stored data (in this case the +dep+ tag and usses this to populate the combobox)...

dose anyboy know how?

I'm ussing vb.net

Answer (score 1):

So you want to take the text after `<dep>` and split it by `;`? Then poulate a combobox with all parts:

```
Dim lineParts = From line In File.ReadLines(path)
                Let depIndex = line.IndexOf("<dep>")
                Where depIndex >= 0
                Select line.Substring(depIndex + 5).Split({";"c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim allParts = lineParts.SelectMany(Function(p) p)
Dim bs = new BindingSource()
bs.DataSource = allParts 
ComboBox1.DataSource = bs
```

If you want unique items only you just have to add `Distinct`:

```
Dim allParts = lineParts.SelectMany(Function(p) p).Distinct()
```